# PHPMailer , keep 1 SMTP Connection with different receiver by email content

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```
$phpMailer = New PHPMailer();
$phpMailer->isSMTP();
$phpMailer->SMTPKeepAlive = true;

for ( ... ) {
    // Send your emails right away
    [ ... ]
}

$phpMailer->SmtpClose();
```

HI, I have an example code for KeepAlive SMTP here, but my problem is I send email with difference contents to my users. So each user have 1 content.

Can I do it like this:

```
 for ( ... ) {
       $phpMailer->addAddress($user['email'], $user['name']);
       $phpMailer->Subject = $user['subject'];
       $phpMailer->Body = $user['body'];
       $phpMailer->Send()
    }
```

Will the ->addAddress increase my recipients every time on the loop? Or will it clean the old recipient after ->send() comitted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call clearAddresses() Before addAddress function . It is cleared before recipients.

```
$phpmailer->ClearAddresses();
$phpMailer->addAddress($user['email'], $user['name']);
```